# acts_as_audited. How can I add a "comment" column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the acts_as_audited gem with my application. (Excellent gem to keep track of changes of model objects)

I have been asked to support associating a text comment with each Audit record (similar functionality to svn commit).  And I am stumped on how to accomplish this.

For example.  Lets say I have an address form, and the user updates City and State, upon hitting save I ask him to provide a Comment.  I would like that comment information associated with the audit record that is created.

Make sense?

Thanks for your help,

Jonathan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought this would be a useful thing. So I forked and patched the plugin myself.

**Edit** My fork has been merged into the official acts_as_audited repository. The usage documentation contained in this post is now applicable to vanilla acts_as_audited. I've changed the links in this post to point there. Get the official repository because mine won't be updated with upstream patches. I have updated the usage documentation in this post to reflect enhancements.

Install it as a plugin:

```
rails_root$ script/plugin install git://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited.git
```

Usage doesn't really change from vanilla acts_as_audited.

acts_as_audited takes an extra option now. :require_comment, which if true, blocks creation, updating, or destruction of an audited model unless a comment is supplied.

To add a comment to an audit use `model.audit_comment= "My Comment"` before create/update/destroy.

audit_comment can also be mass assigned making it simple to add a comment field to any form.

Before you can use my gem/plugin you'll need to update the audit table to contain a comment column. If your're upgrading from an older version of acts_as_audited that doesn't have a comments field on the audit table, update the plugin then run `script/generate audited_migration_update update_audits_table`. Otherwise you're set to go.

With the gem/plugin all that would need to change using your address example adding an audit_comment field to your form.

```
<%form_for @address do |f| %>
  ... standard address fields
  <%= f.label_for :audit_comment %>
  <%= f.text_field :audit_comment %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Amazing!!!!  Talk about going above and beyond.  Thanks a bunch, that worked perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. I realized about halfway through a response that I'd already done most of the work. It seemed like a useful enough thing that it only made sense to make it public.